# typedef std containers?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I wanted to do

```
typedef deque type; //error, use of class template requires template argument list
type<int> container_;
```

But that error is preventing me. How do I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't (until C++0x). But it could be emulated with:

```
template<typename T>
struct ContainerOf
{
  typedef std::deque<T> type;
};
```

used as:

```
ContainerOf<int>::type container_;
```

Answer (score 8):

deque is not a type. It is a template, used to generate a type when given an argument.

```
 deque<int>
```

is a type, so you could do

```
 typedef deque<int> container_
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't, C++ does not yet support this kind of typedef. You can of course say;

```
typedef std::deque <int> IntDeque;
```

Answer (score 1):

You hit an error because you missed to specify int in deque.

But note that: [Template typedef](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Template_typedefs)'s are an accepted C++0x feature. Try with the latest g++

Answer (score 0):

The way you could do this is:

```
#define type deque
```

But that comes with several disadvantages.

Comment: yea, it would turn things like "typename" into "dequename" (I recognize that "type" is an example, but still it's a BIG problem). I would say avoid this at all costs.

Comment: @EvanTeran I realize that this is an extremely old question, so this reply probably isn't that helpful, but #define doesn't just do a find-and-replace for the given string; it only replaces identifiers that are exactly the same as the specified identifier. In this case, "type" would be replaced, but "typename", "types", "Type", "this_type", and a string literal containing the word "type" would not be replaced. Using a macro for a typedef like this is still a bad idea though.

Comment: @EvanBailey LOL, You are totally right, it only replaces whole identifier matches. I'm actually amazed it took TWELVE years for someone to notice that I was completely wrong on it.

Fortunately, the consensus is still that it's just generally a bad idea.