# C++ templated typedef

Tags: c++, templates, typedef

I have a templated class

```
template <T>
class Example 
{
...
};
```

inside which there
are many methods of the following type:

```
template <class U> <class V> method(....)
```

Inside these I use tr1::shared_ptr to U or V or T.

Its tedious typing `tr1::shared_ptr<const U>` or `tr1::shared_ptr<const V>`.

The obvious thing to do:

```
template <typename U>
typedef tr1::shared_ptr<U> shptr<U>;
```

does not work.

What do you do in this situation?  Anything that can reduce verbosity?

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562209/typedef-std-containers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474417/typedef-a-template-class-without-specifying-the-template-parameters, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544842/c-typedef-ing-stl

Comment: I am not sure they are duplicates, they are surely related and might be interesting to browse over the answers, but exact duplicates?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use an inner type:

```
template <typename U>
struct sptr {
    typedef tr1::shared_ptr<U> t;
};
```

Then say `sptr<U>::t`, or unfortunately often `typename sptr<U>::t`.

C++0x has template typedefs, you could check whether your compiler can be persuaded to accept them:

```
template<typename U>
using sptr = tr1::shared_ptr<U>;
```

Then say `sptr<U>`

And of course there's always `#define sptr ::tr1::shared_ptr`, for example if you're expecting C++0x in future and want to bridge the gap. Or if you're using it in a narrow enough context that a macro isn't scary.

Comment: Well, it does a bit in contexts where you don't need `typename`. Otherwise, no, it's not great for something as short as `tr1::shared_ptr<U>`. If it was `std::vector<shared_ptr<U> >::const_iterator` that needed abbreviation, then we might be in business :-)

Answer (score 2):

Nothing to reduce verbosity (except what roe says).

But nice article on problem itself: [Template Typedef](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/079.htm).

You would really *need* this trick if you have some generic function that *expects* your type to have some associated typedef, and your type is templated (consider that you have provide result_t and it should be your template parameter!).

Answer (score 1):

```
using tr1::shared_ptr;
```

should allow you to use `shared_ptr` without prefix, but that's all I know. Sorry.

Comment: Since my templated definitions and declarations have to be in a header file, won't this violate the rule that one should not 
have a using declaration in a header file ?

Comment: @user231536: I don't see why it would HAVE to go in the header file, you can just put it in your source file? It would have to be done in all source files, but would reduce the clutter nonetheless.